# Auto-update pageref fields in rtf document

Tags: ms-word, rtf

The application I'm working on outputs documents to rtf format and PAGEREF fields are used in a table of contents page and an index page. The problem is that on opening the document the fields do not update and remain blank. They work correctly if you manually update the fields in Word. Is there a way to make these fields auto-update in the RTF spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a Document_Open() macro, although you might not be able to add a macro to an rtf file.  You might be able to add a macro at a template (.dot) and have the .rtf file reference the template.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
End Sub
```